# iPad 3 used up 250 MB of LTE data in 3 hours without active usage

Tags: ipad, lte, cellular-data

This morning I purchased 250MB of data from AT&T ahead of the auto-renewal schedule because I had used it up two weeks back. I then checked a few emails without downloading attachments and rode to work. Didn't use the iPad at work, though it would have WiFi there anyway.

About 2 hours after the purchase I receive the usual "only 20% of data left" email and am astounded by that, but go to lunch anyway. When I return from work I have the 10%, 2% and no data left email in my inbox.

I have iCloud Documents (though I only have a few of them), FaceTime and Reading List activated over cellular, but not iTunes. The iPad had been synced the night before, I was not signed in to Skype or similar and I actually didn't use it.

Anybody an idea what might have caused this??

---

I talked to the AT&T help line and all he was able to see is that the data was consumed in 5-6 bursts, not tickling over the three hours. But which service, no idea. I'll visit an Apple Store and check with them, maybe they have means to determine what went awry.

Comment: Did you check this with the usage reported by the iPhone itself? You can check that in Settings - General - Usage.

Comment: Yes, I reset the counter at the beginning of the month where I still had some of a 3GB plan left and it approximately works out (259M out, 575M in).

Comment: Are there any 3rd party apps running that consume data in the background? Do you have cellular data turned off for iCloud as well (it's under iCoud / Documents and Data)?

Comment: Do you know 3rd party apps that would do that? I was not logged in to Skype and not actively using other apps. iCloud data is turned *ON* but since I only have ~80MB worth of docs in iCloud and haven't changed any of it this shouldn't cause this usage. AT&T was really helpful but didn't know what was going on as well, might go visit an Apple store...

Comment: I have had trouble with the Google+ app uploading photos automatically even though I have that feature turned off in the settings.

Comment: I can't make a guess since there haven't been widespread reports of this on AT&T. On the verizon iPads - at 6.0 release, they needed to update a carrier profile to prevent excessive background data (My guess it was a bug specific to how they run their network) but it was patched in a few days and customers affected were refunded or not charged. You might need to grab an app like [netstat](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/netstat/id400071873?mt=8) to see what few processes are using data and see about testing them...

Comment: For comparison, I've have an iPad 4th gen with Verizon LTE for 10 days. I have everything turned on, including Photostream. I don't take many photos and am in wifi range much of the time, but I've been using it quite a lot on LTE. In those 10 days I've only managed to use 70mb.

Comment: Adding to this, I've had this iPad with the same 250MB plan since March and the 250MB always lasted through the month.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Photostream or iTunesMatch there is a good chance that one of the two uses cellular data unexpectedly. As far as I remember there was a problem (before iOS 6) with syncing these two services: when you started the sync in WiFi mode and then switched to cellular (e.g. because of leaving from home), the sync would continue independent of the setting disallowing usage of cellular.

Comment: I have Photostream, but didn't take any pictures in the meantime, they were all synced before. I don't have iTunes Match. I did a cabled sync the night before as well.